# How can I send Azure Application Gateway logs to Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-application-gateway, azure-log-analytics-workspace

How do I get Azure Application Gateway logs in Application Insights?

I have tried Diagnostic Setting where I can send the logs to Log Analytics workspace.

But what I want is: I want to send the logs to Application Insights

Comment: Application Insights is a Application (Web app) based feature where as Application gateway is a networking service used to route the traffic. If you want to collect your web app or app service  based metrics then you use application insights, Otherwise for Application gateway you need to use Log analytics. I am afraid your ask does not seem possible..

Comment: Refer this document to enable Application insights in your app depending on your framework- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview?tabs=net and refer this document to monitor Application gateway- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/monitor-application-gateway

Comment: What does Application Insights offer to you in this scenarion that Log Analytics workspace does not?

Answer (score 0):

Application Insights is an Application- Azure App Service, Web app, Function app performance monitoring service. And Application gateway is a Networking service, thus to monitor Azure Application gateway you need to use Azure Monitor or Log analytics workspace.

Application Insights, You can enable Application insights by using its Instrumentation Key in your code and then get the Metrics and logs from your Web app or App service.

I have enabled Application Insights for my app and it gives me the metrics below:-

This option gives Live Metrics of your app with the multiple endpoints it is reaching to.

[image]

Application insights > Logs >

[image]

Application gateway uses inbuilt ***Insights*** which is a Monitoring feature for Application Gateway which is different from Application insights, But it gives you an insights on the Metrics of Application gateway, Refer below:-

[image]

[image]

As you said, Its better to send your Application Gateway Logs to Log Analytics like below and get insights on the behaviour of your Application Gateway.

[image]

***Refer these [**MS Document1**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview?tabs=net) on Application Insights and this [**MS Document2**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/monitor-application-gateway) on Monitoring Application Gateway. And here are the [**Metrics**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/monitor-application-gateway-reference#resource-logs) that Azure Monitor Diagnostic settings support for application gateway.***

Comment: the problem I faced later was:
+ took the logs to log analytics workspace.
- there was no issue, I could query the logs from there (log analytics workspace).
But I want those logs to be shown in App Insights. Ain't they suppose to appear in the connected App Insight? Because when I created the app insight, I pointed the workspace to that one?

Comment: Application Insight is a different resource and Insights available in Application Gateway > Left pane is different.

Comment: Yes, i am talking about Application Insight